# Getting error in some cases when signing in with GoogleSignInApi

Tags: android, google-signin

When using Google SignIn API, it works correctly in some gmail IDs which is synced in phone but it shows status error in some other gmail IDs.

> Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}

Code:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    System.out.println("helloooo " + result.getStatus().getStatus());
}
```

Since it is working in **some gmail IDs**, I think API console settings are working correctly.

Anybody came across this situation while integrating Google API in Android apps?